# Populating JList from Hashmap and retriving key

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, jlist

How can I populate JList from a HashMap but to have only the value displayed in the list?

I am populating the list with following code. When I start the application I get list items like {1=Value1}, {2=Value2} etc. I want to display just the value.

I am using the HashMap because I need later when I submit the form where JList is to use the keys from values selected for my Insert method and I understood from other examples here that this is done with hashsmap.

```
public void populateListwithCategories(final JList list) {
    try {
        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        List<AdvertisementCategory> advertisementCategories = advertisementCategoryProvider.getAdvertisementCategories();
        for (AdvertisementCategory advertisementCategory : advertisementCategories) {               
            int id = advertisementCategory.getId();
            String name = advertisementCategory.getName();
            advertisementCategory.advertisementMap.put(id, name);
            listModel.addElement(advertisementCategory.advertisementMap); 
        }
        list.setModel(listModel);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AdvertisementCategoryController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AdvertisementCategoryController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This is My AdvertisementCategory model from where I want to export the data to hashmap.

```
public class AdvertisementCategory {

private int id;
private String name, description;
public List<AdvertisementCategory> advertisementCategories;

public Map<Object, String> advertisementMap = new HashMap<>();

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public AdvertisementCategory(int id, String name, String description) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}

public AdvertisementCategory(String name, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}

public AdvertisementCategory() {

}

public AdvertisementCategory(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You are somehow trying to implement a rather complex solution for a non-existing problem.

Using the MVC-principles of Swing, you would add the AdvertisementCategory directly to the list model and implement a `ListCellRenderer` to extract the display value from the AdvertisementCategory instance, which should be shown in the JList itself. Invoking `getSelectedValue()` on the JList will then give you the AdvertisementCategory instance and you have access to all its content.

Comment: No, but you can use Google yourself and find a plenty of good tutorials.